# Extending Craft controller classes and using private methods in child class

Tags: plugin-development, controller, classes

I created Controller that exptends Craft `AssetsController`. Hovewer some of `AssetsController` methods are private - and I cannot use them using `$this` context in child module, so i just copied them to child module.

Is there any other way?

Comment: As they have a private scope, short answer is no. Extending and duping as you currently do. However, it depends on the context and what you want to achieve really, is it a new endpoint and what's the purpose? We would be able to provide better help with extra details

Comment: @RoussKS - I created my own asset controller that does some specific things to uploaded file and works over ajax. And i need methods like `_requirePeerPermissionByAsset` which are private in `AssetsController`.